# Update Chat Every second php

Tags: php, chat

hello here i have i script but this dont work i caant update chat every second can you help me to update chat every second from database (pleasee no uppate div only text)

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        setTimeout(
        function() {updateChat();},
        1000);

        function updateChat() {
        $.get("read.php", function(data)
        {
          $("#Show_Data").html(data);
        });
        }
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Show_Data"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

read.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$Data = "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY Time ASC";
$Result = mysqli_query($Connection, $Data);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo '</br>' .$row['name'];
}

mysqli_free_result($Result);
mysqli_close($Connection);
?>
```

this is my code but my code when insert data in database my code not update data in html

Comment: Now what result do you have?

Comment: Does your get request return the data you require? Please can you clarify which part of your question you are struggling with?

Comment: Don't do this. You'll kill your server with a very small amount of users. Use websockets instead

Comment: @rjdown how to use ?

Comment: Best to google for a tutorial, don't worry though it's simple enough!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){


        setTimeout(
        function() {updateChat();},
        1000);

        function updateChat() 
        {
         $.get("read.php")
         .done(function(data)
         {
           //You can do futher checks here....
           $("#Show_Data").html(data);
           setTimeout(function() {updateChat();},1000);
         })
         .fail(function()
         {
            //error 404 or 500
         });
        }
      });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Show_Data"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Int the code above, when something wrong with the call it stops and it does not continues the executions.

Option2:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(
        function() {updateChat();},
        1000);

        function updateChat() {
        $.get("read.php", function(data)
        {
          $("#Show_Data").html(data);
        });
        }
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Show_Data"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code aboce executed every 1000 miliseconds the ajax call regardless if it is sucessfull the call or not

Comment: this is work correct but div is problem see with inspect element

Comment: I cannot understant your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **setInterval** instead of setTimeout (it runs only once).

If that doesn't help, please post any PHP/JavaScript errors that you are getting.
To make sure PHP errors are set to display, add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top of your script.

To see JavaScript errors, open the Developer Tools (F12) in your browser and go to **Console**.